# Why is this Django form returning unicode?

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have a Django Model Form which I'm using to allow users to update decks they have previously uploaded to the site.  For some reason, though, the cleaned data is coming back as unicode.  So, for instace, if they enter "Deck Foo" as the name, it gets recorded in the database as `(u'Deck Foo',)`.  I have probably 10 other Model Forms across my site and they all work perfectly as expected and I cannot see a single difference between them and this.  Why are these being saved as unicode instead of regular strings?

forms.py

```
class DeckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        fields = ['name', 
                  'format', 
                  'type',
                  'packs',
                  'deck_list',
                  'is_active']

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['type'] == 'COMMANDER' and self.cleaned_data['format'] != 'VINTAGE':
            raise forms.ValidationError('Commander is only played in vintage format.')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def deck_detail(request,
                deck_slug, 
                template_name="deck/deck_detail.html"
                ):

    deck = Deck.objects.get(slug=deck_slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeckForm(request.POST, instance=deck)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            format = form.cleaned_data['format']
            type = form.cleaned_data['type']
            packs = form.cleaned_data['packs']
            deck_list = form.cleaned_data['deck_list']
            is_active = form.cleaned_data['is_active']

            deck.name = name,
            deck.slug = slugify(name),
            deck.format = format,
            deck.type = type,
            deck.packs = packs,
            deck.deck_list = deck_list,
            deck.is_active = is_active

            deck.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/deck/'+deck.slug)
    else:
        form = DeckForm(instance=deck)
```

html

```
<form action="/deck/{{deck.slug}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Deck" />
</form>
```

Comment: `(u'Deck Foo',)` is the string representation of a python tuple with a single unicode element, not unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Justin, now I know :) Certainly makes more sense now that I know what is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are turning `deck.name` into a tuple here.

```
deck.name = name,
```

Your example suggests that your problem is not actually a unicode problem. Rather, a tuple is being inserted into your database instead of a simple unicode string. Try this instead:

```
deck.name = name  # no comma
```

`(u'Deck Foo',)` (in your database) is a string representation of a tuple with a single unicode element. A unicode string would look like this:

```
u'Deck Foo'
```

But your database will simply write the string to the database without the quotation marks or prefixed `u`.

Comment: Commas.  Lol. Why the heck did I put commas there, and why didn't I notice them xD.  Thanks!

Comment: @fildred13 We've all done silly stuff like this before! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: As to your question: all the other attributes were coming in as tuples, I just didn't make it clear.  I meant to say "just to take ONE example, name is blah blah blah"

Comment: @fildred13 Ah, I see! It almost looks like you may have converted a dict or list into the block of code under question and just forgot to remove the commas.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing.